# Eclipse integrating plugin in project

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin with a view and I tried to integrate it into a project. The problem is that I get the error :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2014-08-20 16:17:35.087
!MESSAGE Plugin does not have a valid identifier: plugins/PluginTest.jar
```

and

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2014-08-20 16:17:35.088
!MESSAGE Plugin does not have a valid version: plugins/PluginTest.jar
```

and

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-08-20 16:17:40.138
!MESSAGE Problems occurred restoring workbench.
```

I copied the .jar file in the eclipse/plugin/ folder.
What can be the cause of this errors ?

Comment: Did you create your plugin using 'New > Project > Plug-in Project'? If you did not you will not have the correct values in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Comment: I did this, but I saw something strange, my MANIFEST.MF file contains only the Manifest-Version: 1.0 after the plugin is integrated in the project...everything is deleted after the plugin is integrated in the project, except the Manifest-Version: 1.0 line .

Comment: Never seen that. What do you mean by 'integrated in the project'?

Comment: Adding the plugin to the eclipse actually.....

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Exactly what did you do?

Comment: I copied the plugin in the eclipse/plugins folder and then I added the plugin to the build path and gave me the above error. I have to add a plugin that I'm creating now, but before adding the plugin that I'm creating I tried with a plugin from the template (a plugin with sample view), to see if I'm able to run it on a project.

Comment: If you want to install a plugin in Eclipse you must use 'Export > Plug-in Development > Deployable plug-ins and fragments' to create a proper plugin jar

Comment: Read [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html) especially the part about deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a Eclipse plugin project using 'File > New >  Project.. > Plug-in Project'.

This will prompt you for values such as the plugin id and version and create a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file containing these values.

[image]

A minimal version of the `MANIFEST.MF` might look like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: PluginTest
Bundle-SymbolicName: PluginTest;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
```

Other files important for plugins such as the `build.properties` will also be created and the 'plugin nature' will be added to `.project` file which makes many plugin specific entries appear in the Project Properties and context menus.

Answer (score 1):

Is the plugin's header right?

Maybe it doesn't have the version on it's header, here is an example:

```
    Plugin Name: Test Plugin
    Plugin URI: http://testUri
    Description: Testing description
    Author: Us
    Version: 0.1-alpha
    Author URI: http://myProfile
    Text Domain: testing
    Domain Path: /lang
```

Here is a good link: http://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header

Are you building the plugin or just downloaded it?

Comment: I built  my own plugin and I had the same problem. Then I started a project with view from template and package it to .jar and after that I tried to run that sample view from a project and it gives the same error as my plugin.

Comment: For Eclipse, these need to go into the file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. Eclipse has special editors for it.

Comment: These are not the entries needed for an Eclipse plugin.